# Reading Google Universal Analytics fields in JavaScript

Tags: google-analytics

I know I can override certain default values in Universal Analytics analytics.js:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding

but how would I go about reading Google's default values in to my own JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

All covered here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#get

but it looks like you can only retrieve fields already manually set, rather than the default values.